# How can I change excel tab color using PHPExcel?

Tags: phpexcel

I need to change tab color to red in my sheet

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('SHEET1');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getTab->setColor( new PHPExcel_Style_Color( PHPExcel_Style_Color::COLOR_RED ) );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a way

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getTabColor()->setARGB(PHPExcel_Style_Color::COLOR_RED);
```

or set desired colors by hex values

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getTabColor()->setARGB('ff0000');
```