# How can I adjust the bottom scrollbar to show all my multiple sheets using PHPExcel?

Tags: phpexcel

I just want to change the bottom scrollbar to accommodate all my multiple sheets, from this: [image: before] to look like this:[image: after]

As you can see, my eight sheets aren't visible by default and the bottom tab scrollbar needs to be manually adjusted in excel.

I could find anything on this besides each sheet's own vertical/horizontal scrollbar. [Changing each sheet tab's color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61371544/how-can-i-change-excel-tab-color-using-phpexcel) is roughly related but now I need to adjust this.

Can this can be done in PHPExcel or is it out of scope?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of scope; and PHPExcel has been abandoned for a number of years now, so it will never be in scope